# pdb: recover data from "need more than X values to unpack"?

Tags: python, pdb

I got this error: `ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack` and was dumped out to a pdb prompt (actually, `ipdb>`).  It happens that the computation was very expensive and I don't want to repeat it.

The function call looked like:

```
x,y,z = f(q)
```

Is there any way to recover what `f(q)` was going to return, given that I still have a live `pdb` session?

EDIT: to clarify, `f(q)` is extremely computationally expensive and cannot be repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> def func():x,y,z=f()
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(func)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (f)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          3
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
             12 STORE_FAST               1 (y)
             15 STORE_FAST               2 (z)
             18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             21 RETURN_VALUE
```

Looking at how unpacking works it looks like the error is raised at `UNPACK_SEQUENCE` step, means before storing any value, so I guess you can't recover the returned values.

Comment: to clarify: I understand exactly what caused the `Exception`, and know exactly how to fix it, but I need to know if I can do anything about the data that is presumably hovering in memory somewhere, unassigned to any variable.

Comment: @keflavich Any object with zero references is automatically garbage collected in python.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `dis`, that's useful.  I was hoping that there was some lingering hidden-variable reference, e.g. some magical unpacker iterator, but I suspect not.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to issue a simple print statement:

```
print f(q)
```